# How to check if a Photoshop PSD file's embedded thumbnail is accordance with it's content

Tags: python, thumbnails, photoshop, psd

Sometimes, we change psd documents without Photoshop, like with psd-tools with python,
We can make modifications to it's contents but there's no way to update it's embedded thumbnail,

Sometimes it's confusing to see a psd file open appear different to it's preview.

Comment: For a quick solution, can you not write out a separate preview using psd-tools?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to extract thumbnail image with psd-tools:  
`from psd_tools import PSDImage  
PSDImage.open('input.psd').thumbnail().save("thumb.png")`

Comment: OK, then I can compare the original psd file and the extracted thumbnail.